# final static SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()

Tags: java

Here is my annotated code.

```
class RandomThing{

// This is one way to do it, but I want more randomness.
    protected final static Random rand = new Random();

// This is how I do it with SecureRandom.
    protected final static Random rand = new SecureRandom();

// Here is the best way I can get a strong instance, but rand is no longer final.
    protected static Random rand = null;

    static {
        try {
            rand = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            // Blow up.
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have something like this?

```
protected final static Random rand = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
// not okay because getInstanceStrong throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
```

Comment: *but rand is no longer final*: that's because you removed the `final` keyword. Add it back, and remove the useless `= null`.

Comment: @JBNizet If the field is `final` and `static` it needs to be initialized at declaration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: nope. A static block can initialize a static final field. It can't be initialized more than once, though.

Comment: @JB I can't, because I have to catch an exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Right. But because of the multiple branches...(is what I was missing)

Comment: Just take the above RandomThing code, add `final` to the `rand` declaration, and remove the `= null`, and it will compile fine (if you remove the two other `rand` fields, of course).

Comment: @JB It doesn't. My IDE gives me an error for the exception that `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` can throw.

Comment: Put `rand = null` in the `catch` block (or do something else drastic, like throw an unchecked exception).